# How to send a error message in a specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want my bot to send errors and warns into my private server, but I have no idea how to do it. Also is it possible to send it in a embed? And where & who triggered the error? Thanks!

This is what I tried:

```
client.on("error", (e) => {
    client.channels.cache.get(`825634835572719658`).send(e)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find channel by it's name as follows:

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === channelName)
channel.send(message)
```

Create embed message like as follows

```
let embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle("This is an error").setColor(0x7dd9e8)
```

You should be able to combine both to send an embed message to a channel!

Alternatively, with newer discord.js versions you can also do as follows:

```
// The channel that you want to send the messages to
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('channel id')

client.on('message',message => {
  // Ignore bots
  if (message.author.bot) return
  // Send the embed
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(message.content)
    .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
  channel.send(embed).catch(console.error)
})
```

Comment: @Axmyo If this did help please consider marking it approved